# How is load balancing in big systems implemented?

Tags: load-balancing

I'm wondering how is implemented load balancing in realy big applications like google or facebook. I know that in normal scenario there may be machine dedicated to this task, but I would like to know how is it resolved in realy big aplication with hundreds of thousans people accessing it in any given time. I am just wondering how exactly when one types google.com will that request find its way to concrete computer (are there multiple load balancers? and how is it set up and implemented that user's request will find the way to concrete balancer out of many others). I will realy appreciate if someone enlightens me this issue, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's Wikipedia's explanation: [Load balancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29)

The bigger the system, the more equipment dedicated to load balancing.